# Close popup making it disapear from DOM and enable it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this button showing a popup made by html and css only, i want to make the popup disapear from DOM when i close it clicking on "delete from dom" button on the popup which is working, but i didn't find the opposite of "removeChild()" method to enable it once it is closed, i did try "appendChild()" which didn't worked for me. Thank you.

```js
  function del() {
var elem = document.querySelector('#popup1');

elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button"  href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
 
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <a class="close"  href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
      Text
      <input type="submit" value="delete from dom" onclick=del() />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once it is removed from DOM it is gone;
you would have to recreate the dom fragment..
usually, in a case like this, you would only hide/show it through CSS.

Comment: @maioman If you keep a reference to the element, it won't be garbage collected, so, you can readd with `appendChild`. (I didn't try, but it should work...)

Comment: You can save it before the deletion in a variable so you can add it again after deletion.

Comment: @Mr.Jo How can i store the html of the popup in a var, and recall it  ?

Comment: let element = elem.cloneNode();

Comment: @Mr.Jo No need to clone, just `let element = elem`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to delete the popup from the DOM, you have to keep a reference to it (in a variable).

You also have to save the parent (`.parentNode` obviously won't work while the element is removed and has no parent):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#popup1');
var parent = elem.parentNode

function del() {
  parent.removeChild(elem);
}

function add() {
  parent.appendChild(elem)
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .box {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button" href="#popup1" onclick="add()">Let me Pop up</a>

</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      Text
      <input type="submit" value="delete from dom" onclick="del()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to delete it or just hide it? Here I use the route to hide it (just as you use the route to show it) by removing the hash part of the url `window.location.href = '#'`.

```js
function del() {
  window.location.href = '#'
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button"  href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <a class="close"  href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
      Text
      <input type="submit" value="Hide Pop-Up" onclick=del() />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only hides it instead deleting it so to name the button "Delete from DOM" is not correct I think.

Comment: I want to delete if from DOM and enable it

Comment: @aliouawalid Try to save it in a variable like in my comment. You can use the var now to append the content back to the dom.